# Keeping track of dynamic webpage status with PHP and UUIDs

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, uuid, status

I'm building an e-commerce from scratch and there are many actions that a user can do without being logged in (adding items to the cart, creating his own custom product). To solve this I generate a cookie containing a UUID, store the UUID in a MySQL table "Users", and associate every information to that UUID. When the users eventually registers an account, I store nickname, hash, salt and e-mail in a "Registered_Users" table that is associated to the original UUID (i could even use a single table with NULL fields, but that's not the point), that becomes useless if not to retrieve pieces of information about the user when not registered.

What if a user deletes cookies? Is UUID a good choice for this task?

Please note that the whole e-commerce is going to be behind SSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chosen system looks fine to me. Regarding your question "What if a user deletes cookies", it has two consequences.

First, the user loses his cart and individual products. But this is somehow expected behavior, so I wouldn't worry about it. If you are really concerned that the user should not lose all his valuable data when he doesn't register, think of other methods of storing your UUID, for example localStorage or Flash cookies. For a list of all the possibilities (many of them not advisable for your application) see http://samy.pl/evercookie/

Second, your database table with UUIDs and other data will grow over time. So from time to time you need to delete old entries where the user did not register for an account. Your two tables make this relatively trivial to identify users who did not register. Here is how a cleanup of old entries could be done with SQL:

```
DELETE FROM Users WHERE date_created < '2012-01-01' AND 
  UUID NOT IN (SELECT UUID FROM Registered_Users);
```

I chose a fixed date here to avoid the `DATEDIFF` function.
You'd probably need to delete the other data first before deleting the users.

Have a look at [this article](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/03/13/to-uuid-or-not-to-uuid/) to form your own opinion if UUIDs are a good choice from and database and performance standpoint. Maybe just using the autoincremented primary key from `Users` will suffice.

Comment: What is a good criteria to decide whether an unregistered user should be "cleaned-up" or not? A fixed inactivity time seems too shallow to me.

Comment: Using auto_increment creates a concurrency problem. The steps would have to be something like: 1) Create a new row 2) Retrieve the ID and store it in a cookie. This operation would have to be atomic and I don't think it's possible in PHP/MySQL without using transactions (which I'd like to avoid as much as possible).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with 'shallow'. If you don't use the creation date but the last activity time instead and choose a big interval (30+ days), you should be pretty safe to delete only users who aren't returning or have deleted cookies. If two concurrent requests create a record in `Users`, the entries will have different autoincrement IDs and calls to `PDO::lastInsertId` or `mysqli->insert_id` will return two different IDs which you can then store in the cookie. A single `INSERT` statement (without using transactions) is quite atomic.